# Can't assign to an array because it's not implemented

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays

```
Ships.TokenHarvest[][] public nameToCost;

function addNameToCost(Ships.TokenHarvest[][] memory costs) public onlyOwner {
    nameToCost = costs;
}
```

The above code gives this error:

```
Copying of type struct Ships.TokenHarvest memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
```

What exactly is the issue here and how can i solve it so that i can assign my input variable to the storage variable?

Comment: the "nameToCost" is a storage variable, and your "costs" is in memory. In solidity, you cannot yet copy the array directly from memory into storage. you probably need to iterate over the array and add the items individually. I'm not sure if that is the only error  in your code.. working with array and struct is very painful

Comment: Thanks doing a nested for loop and copying everything over worked